# Auto populate CPQ Quote when a new Quote is created

Tags: cpq

Based on customer's requirement, I am trying to create new CPQ Quote button (URL) on Opportunity . The expectation here is pre-populate some of the attributes on the CPQ Quote such as Opportunity, Account, RecordType, and other custom fields (mostly picklist). I created the following 2 buttons

Button #1

```
{!If
(
OR
($User.UIThemeDisplayed == 'Theme4d',
$User.UIThemeDisplayed == 'Theme4t'),
URLFOR("/lightning/o/Quote/new?&defaultFieldValues=SBQQ__Opportunity2__c="&Opportunity.Id&",SBQQ__Account__c="&Opportunity.AccountId&",SBQQ__SalesRep__c="&Opportunity.OwnerId&" "),
URLFOR("/0Q0/e?retURL="&Opportunity.Id&"&oppid="&Opportunity.Id&"&Name="&Opportunity.Name&" "))}
```

Button #2

```
    /lightning/o/SBQQ__Quote__c/new?defaultFieldValues=SBQQ__Opportunity2__c={!Opportunity.Opportunity_ID__c},SBQQ__Account__c={!Opportunity.Account_ID__c}
```

Both the above the options doesn't work. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

There's a variety of different ways, but the correct solution will depend on your specific needs. Looking at what you've attempted, your needs seem simple enough that you could make a quick action to create a new Quote and preset values.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I try to create New Action, there is no option to select CPQ Quote in the Target Object. So Quick Actions is not a way to go.

Comment: It will just be called "Quote." I can see it in my instance.

Comment: I thought it was standard Quote and not CPQ Quote that is strange, cos I renamed the CPQ Quotes from 'Quotes' to 'CPQ Quote'. Since the Customer is still using standard Quotes object.

Comment: Yeah that appears to be one place where relabeled names don't show up.

Comment: What if Quick Action is not a way, what approach would you recommend. Because the one above is not working. I created URL buttons for other objects and passing parameters its working fine. But not for CPQ Quote, I reckon at the backend is the vf page and that is causing this issue.